# Swipe table view cell in ios7 Simulator

Tags: ios7, cucumber, calabash

I am unable to swipe table view cell in ios7 simulator.

1. Calabash version: 0.9.167
2. Ruby: 1.9.3

Is there any work around? Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue and is the result of a bug in the iOS 7 iPhone Simulator.

It is being tracked here:

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/253